# How to place turtles inside certain areas based on patch colour

Tags: netlogo

I have 3 breeds for my model - wolves, prey, livestock.

My environment is built into 3 circles of differing colors, dark green center, light green around that and green around it all.

I have been able to place the wolves in their "den" which is easy because its at 0'0 so simple xcor ycor code was used.

But how do I place the livestock in the outer green circle only and the prey species allowed in the dark green center and light green second circle

code below for setup

```
to setup

clear-all
ask patches [set pcolor green - 1]
 ask patch 50 50
  [
   set pcolor white
    ask patches in-radius .8 [set pcolor white]
    ask patches in-radius 40 with [pcolor != white] [set pcolor green - 3]
     ask  patches in-radius 50 with [pcolor != white and pcolor != green - 3] [set pcolor green]
    ]

  create-adults 2
  ask adults [ set color black set shape "wolf" setxy 50 50 set energy 32400 set size 1]

   create-subadults 2
  ask subadults [ set color grey set shape "wolf" setxy 50 50 set energy 32400 set size 1]

   create-juveniles 4
  ask juveniles [ set color brown set shape "wolf" setxy 50 50 set energy 15000 set size .8]

    create-prey 40 [ set color brown ]
  ask prey [ set color brown set shape "deer" setxy random-xcor random-ycor set energy 3000 set size 2]

   create-livestock 30
  ask livestock [ set color white set shape "cow" setxy random-xcor random-ycor set energy 20000 set size 2]


set territory-patches patches with [pcolor =  green - 3]
set non-territory-patches patches with [pcolor =  green ]

  reset-ticks

end
```

Comment: If you've already created the patch conditions, it is often easier to use `sprout` than `create`. You can get the patches to generate a turtle of the correct type and then add a small random movement so it's on the same patch that generated it but not in the centre of the patch.

Comment: this worked, thanks a million!